# .txt file to char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, iostream

I have been trying to read a .txt file with the following text :

> Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it. - Brian W. Kernighan *

However when I try to send the .txt file to my char array, the whole message except for the word "Debugging" prints out, I'm not sure why. Here's my code. It must be something simple that I can't see, any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

char quote[300];

ifstream File;

File.open("lab4data.txt");

File >> quote;


File.get(quote, 300, '*');


cout << quote << endl;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense, even if deliberately read as pseudo code. can you please try to improve your question to  explain what you actually want to achieve please.

Comment: Remove `File >> quote;` this is when the first word is written to the array and then overwritten by the call to `File.get`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it

Comment: Preferably use `std::string` instead of `char[n]`.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
File >> quote;
```

reads the first word into your array. Then the next call to `File.get` copies over the word that you already read. So the first word is lost.

You should remove the above line from your code and it will function correctly.

I'd usually suggest using a `std::string` instead of a char array to read into, but I can see that `ifstream::get` does not support it, closest is `streambuf`.

The other thing to watch is to check that your file opened correctly.

The following code does that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char quote[300];
    ifstream file("kernighan.txt");

    if(file)
    {
        file.get(quote, 300, '*');
        cout << quote << '\n';
    } else
    {
        cout << "file could not be opened\n";
    }    
}
```

The `ifstream` object is convertible to `bool` (or `void*` in c++03 world) and so can be tested against for truthiness.

Answer (score 0):

A simple char by char read method ( not tested)

## include

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    char quote[300];
    ifstream File;
    File.open("lab4data.txt");
    if(File)
    {
         int i = 0;
         char c;
         while(!File.eof())
         {
             File.read(&c,sizeof(char));
             quote[i++] =c;
         }   
         quote[i]='\0';          
         cout << quote << endl;
         File.close();
    }
```

}